# Property Change Event WPF Original to change

Tags: wpf

I am new to WPF and piecing it together as I go along, but there is a property change event that  is attached to fields that I am utlizing to know when something has changed, off those events is their a way to know if the value has changed is different then from the original value and back and forth, right now I have a collection of default values that I am checking against to know is something has changed and also when I have to reassign the default values the property event keeps getting fired

Comment: Are you talking about public properties with backing private fields using Raise or OnPropertyChanged in the public property? Or are you talking about inside a property changed event handler hooked up through the xaml?

Comment: Kind of a vague question tbh without seeing actual code. calling property changed(for INPC) without the backing value changing is generally bad since that's going to trigger a unwanted refresh(in most cases) in the UI if it's bound. So in MVVM and VM's almost all properties if they fire a INPC event, the property has likely changed. But again without seeing code none of this is a guarantee cos you might have some cases where you do want to fire property changed even when the value did not change.

Comment: I am talking about public properties using raise and onProperty change, is their a way to have default values their and know if some case something was changed and then change back to its original

Comment: Yes most likely, but the comparison you need depends on the exact situation. As you can see from my answer you can check the value of "value" vs the backing field any way you wish. And you really only need to call OnPropertyChanged if the property really changed. You can use the setter of the property to check any conditions and then set your backing field and call OnPropertyChanged depending on the conditions.

Comment: Why would you want to change a value back to the original?  If you don't want it to be changed then don't have a set.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there will be a backing private field for these public properties where you have Raise or OnPropertyChanged being called (however you do it).  You can usually compare the incoming "value" to the backing field before you set it.  So any type of comparison of the incoming value vs the value that the field is before being set can be done right there in the property setter.
Something like this

```
private bool bMyBool;
public bool MyBool
{
     get
     {
         return bMyBool;
     }
     set
     {
         // Can do comparison here
         // if (value == bMyBool)
         //     DoSomething
         bMyBool = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("MyBool"); // Or some type on property changed notification
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the value changed then just eliminate the get

```
private string myValue = "default";
public string MyValue;
{
   get { return myValue; }
   set 
   {
      if (myValue == value) return;
      myValue = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged(MyValue);
   }
}
```

If you want to change the value but not NotifyPropertyChanged then you could assign

```
myValue = "no notitfy";
```

Rare you would want to do that